# LNK2005 error when linking multiple projects that use boost

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, linker, boost-asio

I have a project that consists from one main project, 3 projects that use boost and few other projects that links to static libraries. These 3 projects use boost. But I can't build my main project. I've got a lot of `error LNK2005: .... already defined in ...` 
errors. As I understood, boost automaticaly links libraries to both of this projects. I tried to use **BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB**, but it didn't work. After adding this macro I've got unresolved symbols errors, but the redefinition errors still here. How can I solve this problem?

UPD1: there about 400+ errors. Here are first of them:

```
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(VS_Project_with_boost_1.obj) : error LNK2005: "unsigned long __cdecl boost::asio::detail::win_tss_ptr_create(void)" (?win_tss_ptr_create@detail@asio@boost@@YAKXZ) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(VS_Project_with_boost_1.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl boost::asio::detail::do_throw_error(class boost::system::error_code const &,char const *)" (?do_throw_error@detail@asio@boost@@YAXABVerror_code@system@3@PBD@Z) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(VS_Project_with_boost_1.obj) : error LNK2005: "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::asio::error::get_misc_category(void)" (?get_misc_category@error@asio@boost@@YAABVerror_category@system@3@XZ) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(VS_Project_with_boost_1.obj) : error LNK2005: "protected: static void __cdecl boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::startup(struct boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data &,unsigned char,unsigned char)" (?startup@winsock_init_base@detail@asio@boost@@KAXAAUdata@1234@EE@Z) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(VS_Project_with_boost_1.obj) : error LNK2005: "protected: static void __cdecl boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::cleanup(struct boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data &)" (?cleanup@winsock_init_base@detail@asio@boost@@KAXAAUdata@1234@@Z) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(VS_Project_with_boost_1.obj) : error LNK2005: "protected: static void __cdecl boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::throw_on_error(struct boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data &)" (?throw_on_error@winsock_init_base@detail@asio@boost@@KAXAAUdata@1234@@Z) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(VS_Project_with_boost_1.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::post_deferred_completions(class boost::asio::detail::op_queue<class boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation> &)" (?post_deferred_completions@win_iocp_io_service@detail@asio@boost@@QAEXAAV?$op_queue@Vwin_iocp_operation@detail@asio@boost@@@234@@Z) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(VS_Project_with_boost_1.obj) : error LNK2005: "struct boost::asio::detail::signal_state * __cdecl boost::asio::detail::get_signal_state(void)" (?get_signal_state@detail@asio@boost@@YAPAUsignal_state@123@XZ) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(VS_Project_with_boost_1.obj) : error LNK2005: _boost_asio_signal_handler already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(VS_Project_with_boost_1.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl boost::asio::detail::signal_set_service::deliver_signal(int)" (?deliver_signal@signal_set_service@detail@asio@boost@@SAXH@Z) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(Some_file.obj) : error LNK2005: "unsigned long __cdecl boost::asio::detail::win_tss_ptr_create(void)" (?win_tss_ptr_create@detail@asio@boost@@YAKXZ) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(Some_file.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl boost::asio::detail::do_throw_error(class boost::system::error_code const &,char const *)" (?do_throw_error@detail@asio@boost@@YAXABVerror_code@system@3@PBD@Z) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(Some_file.obj) : error LNK2005: "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::asio::error::get_misc_category(void)" (?get_misc_category@error@asio@boost@@YAABVerror_category@system@3@XZ) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
1>Project_with_boost_1.lib(Some_file.obj) : error LNK2005: "protected: static void __cdecl boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::startup(struct boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data &,unsigned char,unsigned char)" (?startup@winsock_init_base@detail@asio@boost@@KAXAAUdata@1234@EE@Z) already defined in Project_with_boost_2.lib(asio.obj)
```

UPD2: I also tried to use macros kind of **BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_LIB**, **BOOST_ASIO_NO_LIB**. Result is the same as by using **BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB**

UPD3: I can set linker option in my main project **"Force File Output"** to **"Multiply Defined Symbols Only /FORCE:MULTIPLE"** and project compiles successfully, but during execution it crashes, so I can't use this option.

Comment: Are you using boost libs as dlls and using `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`? You need to post some code because this could be lots of things. It might have absolutely nothing to do with boost, in fact. In fact it could be nearly anything. Definitely need at the very least the complete compiler and linker phase console output, not just `error LNK2005` - this tells us absolutely nothing.

Comment: By using **BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK** I've got same errors.

Comment: You've got to post more about your errors. My bet is that the error codes give away exactly what the real issue is. They're designed to do that. :)

Comment: Yes, I thought this was the problem. You're including asio inside of dll's aren't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issues have nothing to do with auto linking. The issue is the fact that you've imported boost::asio, a header only library that has some global state, into two separate binaries and linked them together (probably one or more dlls and an exe).

By doing this, you're creating more than one definition of these objects/functions, hence the `LNK2005` errors. A bit on that in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10046485/562566). You need to follow what the manual says about this situation, and build properly. From [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html):

> **Optional separate compilation**
>
> By default, Boost.Asio is a header-only library. However, some
>   developers may prefer to build Boost.Asio using separately compiled
>   source code. To do this, add `#include <boost/asio/impl/src.hpp>` **to one
>   (and only one)** source file in a program, then build the program with
>   `BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION` defined in the project/compiler
>   settings. Alternatively, `BOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK` may be defined to build a
>   separately-compiled Boost.Asio as part of a shared library.

Emphasis mine. Make sure you define `BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION` is all associated projects that include boost::asio. About the `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` option, pretend this flag doesn't exist. It's evil, as you can see. It's throwing errors in the garbage that were there to tell you that something is seriously wrong.

Comment: Thank you good man! God bless you!!! I added to depend-projects macro **BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION** with **BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB** and in main project added to linker input necessary libraries and it compiled! Thank you once again!!

Comment: No problem, same to you. However, you shouldn't need `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` anymore. Just use `BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION`.