# Error with a linked file, Error LNK2005 in VS 2015

Tags: c++

The thing is I am keeping the main code in one file and calling functions from the other file. But it gives me LNK 2005 error every time I try to compile it. Can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong here? I am a newbie in C++ so please help me.

main file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "forwards.cpp" // All the functions are forwarded in this file.

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Approximate Age Calculator till 31-12-2015" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Type your birth year: ";
    cin >> yy;
    cout << "Type your birth month: ";
    cin >> mm;
    cout << "Type your day of birth: ";
    cin >> dd;
    cout << "Your approximate age is ";
    cout << yearCalculator() << " years, ";
    cout << monthCalculator() << " months and ";
    cout << daysCalculator() << " days" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

forwards.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int dd;
int mm;
int yy;
int a;

int daysCalculator()
{
    int a = 31 - dd;
    return a;
}
int monthCalculator()
{
    int a = 12 - mm;
    return a;
}
int yearCalculator()
{
    int a = 2015 - yy;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the file `stdafx.h`  in the same directory as the other two files?

Comment: Please include the code in the question. Linking to images, will get you nothing but downvotes!!

Comment: The issue is that you have a cpp file included in another cpp file. But visual studio tries to build each source file in the project as a separate translation unit and then link it all together. So hence it compiles `forward.cpp` twice. Once as part of main and once by itself. This is the reason for the duplications in the error messages.  Simplest fix, is probably to remove the #include.

Comment: What you should really do is create a `forward.h` that includes prototypes for the functions in forward.cpp at least and probably `extern` statements for the variables.

Comment: okay I should try that first. I will let you know what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Paul, It helped. The other file was getting compiled twice and that's why it was not working. But creating a header file worked.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046514/1566267

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have a cpp file included in another cpp file. But visual studio tries to build each source file in the project as a separate translation unit and then link it all together. So hence it compiles `forwards.cpp` twice. Once as part of main and once by itself. This is the reason for the duplications in the error messages. Simplest fix, is probably to remove the #include.

What you should really do is create a `forwards.h` that includes prototypes for the functions in `forwards.cpp` at least and probably extern statements for the variables.

Another thing you should maybe also consider is using a class to encapsulate the variables you have. It's not normally good form to export variables on their own from another file. I can give you an example of this.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

// The class could be in another file
class AgeCalculator
{
    int year_;
    int month_;
    int day_;

public:
    AgeCalculator(int year, int month, int day)
        : year_(year), month_(month), day_(day)
    {}

    int GetYear() { return (2015 - year_); }
    int GetMonth() { return (12 - month_); }
    int GetDay() { return (31 - day_); }
};

int main()
{
    int y, m, d;

    cout << "enter year :";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "enter month :";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "enter day :";
    cin >> d;

    AgeCalculator ac(y, m, d);

    cout << "Your approximate age is " << 
        ac.GetYear() << " years " << 
        ac.GetMonth() << " months and " << 
        ac.GetDay() << " days.\n";
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped, feel free to accept my answer by clicking the tick on the left.