# How to include Caffe to Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, build, linker, nuget, caffe

I'm not asking how to build Caffe under Windows, did that. But now wondering how to include Caffe to my project to use it as a library...

Now I see following folder, which has headers:

> caffe\include\caffe

and build, which has .exe, .dll and some .lib files in it:

> caffe\Build\x64\Debug

So I've added includes to Additional Include Directories in my project, and for Linker - folder with Build.

Tried to build my project, but recieved a lot of errors saying about unresolved dependencies, for example, boost, which is used by Caffe project to build via Nuget.

So I shloud include all those packadges(about 12) via Nuget to my project, this is how it works? Or there is other way and I am doing something wrong?

Any advise and explanation of build mechanics would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it today. However, I know nothing about Nuget and I'm no expert in build mechanics. So my solution is surely messy and far from optimal, but it worked for me so I hope it can help you too. I assume you used the official windows branch led by microsoft (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows), here are the steps I followed:

### Add libCaffe project to your solution

- Copy these files to your project folder :

  - caffe\windows\CommonSettings.targets
  - caffe\windows\CommonSettings.props
  - caffe\windows\scritps\ folder
- Right click your solution -> *add existing project* -> select caffe\windows\libcaffe\libcaffe.vcxproj

### Add libcaffe as a reference

According to these issues : 
https://github.com/Microsoft/caffe/issues/48
https://github.com/Microsoft/caffe/issues/45

- *Project properties -> common properties -> References -> Add a new reference*
- Select libcaffe
- Set *Use Library Dependency Inputs* as **True**

### Add includes

Project properties-> Config settings -> C/C++ ->General -> other include directories -> select a directory with all includes needed :

This is where I am quite sure we can find better because I had to gather all the include directories from caffe (caffe\include) and all it's dependencies (gflags, glog, etc...) by hand. Just try to compile from time to time to see what's missing.

### Add libraries

First, give the path where you will gather all libraries : 
Project properties -> Config settings -> Linker -> General -> Additional library directories

Then you have to explicitly link (at least I had to) : P*roject properties -> Config settings -> Linker -> Input -> additionnal dependencies*

Here are the one I had to add : 
cudart.lib;cuda.lib;nppi.lib;cufft.lib;cublas.lib;curand.lib;Shlwapi.lib;hdf5.lib;hdf5_hl.lib;opencv_highgui2410.lib;opencv_core2410.lib;

Plus some others that are in "inherited values" : cpprest120_2_6.lib
cudnn.lib;gflags.lib;gflags_nothreads.lib;leveldb.lib;libglog.lib;libhdf5.lib;libhdf5_hl.lib;libopenblas.dll.a;libprotobuf.lib;lmdb.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib

Maybe some of it are specific to my application, but at least these worked for me.

You can find most of them in the extracted folder "NugetPackages".

### Additional problem

In my case, I was using boost 1.56 in my project, but caffe uses the 1.59 version, so there was a conflict, I followed an answer from [error LNK2005, already defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046485/error-lnk2005-already-defined) and added the FORCE:MULTIPLE option : *Project properties -> Config settings -> Linker -> General -> Force output*

Again, this may not be the best solution, any time I use "FORCE"-something, I get this bad feeling...

### Add dlls in the executable directory

You should find most of them in the build directory. I was missing libgflags which I downloaded from https://github.com/ChenglongChen/caffe-windows/tree/master/bin

Hope this helps.

PS : My Visual is in French, I tried to translate the options as well as i could.