# How do I fix already defined -main in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors

I have no background knowledge about programming, only experience I have is a little html coding in school. I literally started 2 days ago learning c++ and currently learning input and output streams, don't even understand debugging yet. I started a Visual Studio Project and wrote a second program, simple hello world, just like in the first. But this time, error occurred, _main is already defined in the .obj of the first program. What does this mean, what is the problem, how can I counter it and keep on working?
Error LNK2005   _main
I looked up the error code and understood nothing let alone found out how to fix it. Easy answers please.
Thanks in advance

Program:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World2" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to create one project per one main.

Comment: FWIW, I think it's much better to learn C++ programming using g++/clang. Visual Studio is geat for editing and debugging but is has a steeper learning curve.

Comment: You should avoid *precompiled headers* until your programs are large and warrant the savings.  Otherwise it will generate a lot of issues for you.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews but I do need precompiled headers to execute programs with, don't I?

Comment: @RSahu A friend of mine also recommended, learning with a compiler and I tried but I understood less in terms of usage as in working with visual studio. I know it's a bit unconventional learning this way but I'm willing to go this way if it works out eventually

Comment: No, you don't need to use precompiled headers.  I've been programming in C and C++ for many decades and don't use precompiled headers.  One recurring issue that I had was that header files kept changing, so the compiler was always rebuilding (recompiling) the precompiled header.  So, in that case, there wasn't any benefit.  Also, precompiled headers are useful when you have huge source code (for example, including Windows *and* other big libraries like WxWidgets).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You mean headers like pch.h, right? But iostream is a header too or is it different with iostream?

Comment: The build time savings for small programs, with precompiled headers, is negligible.  Your build may be take long depending on other programs that are running on your PC (like music, videos, etc.).

Comment: The `pch.h` is a *precompiled header*, composed of all your headers.  It is not standard (some compilers use `stdafx.h`).  The `iostream` is a standard header.  *Note:  the standard headers may not exist as separate files, but may be intrinsic to the compiler.*

Comment: @ThomasMatthews But what is the pch.h used for?

Comment: If I have one or more header files, the compiler will compile the data in the header files into `pch.h`.  Consider `pch.h` as a compressed file containing one or more include files.  Precompiling a header means that the compiler doesn't have to parse the text of an include file; it can refer directly to the data in the `pch.h` file.  Search the internet for "c++ precompiled header".  Try removing your `pch.h` include statement and any compiler options for precompiled headers and rebuild your program.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046485/error-lnk2005-already-defined/19740915#19740915) answer of mine should also apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two files (.cpp) in your visual studio project each containing a `main` or `_tmain` function, link will fail because there can only be one `main` function defined.

Rename all other `main` function and you'll be fine.

Comment: I tried naming the second main "main(1)" but it wasn't accepted. Should I name it differently and will that affect the program?

Comment: Name it main_1() ans you'll be ready to learn and experiment with c++.

Comment: So I just name it main_1() now, main_2() in the next file and so on? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: But I can't use the same "main_1()" in the same file again right?

Comment: I added a cout function to the program depicted above, can't I use another process in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project and paste your code in the new file and check. Execution of a program starts from main() method in every programming language, so can't have more than one main() method in the single program."Error LNK2005 _main" occurs when you define main() method more than ones.

Comment: What does define really mean  and how is it executed? I still didn't understand that