# Cannot make function public. Getting: "LNK2005" error. How to debug linker errors

Tags: c++

there is only one definition of MyFourierClass::forward_fft in my project. When I declare MyFourierClass::forward_fft as public, I get this error, otherwise there is no error.

Error Message:

```
1>my_fourier.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl MyFourierClass::forward_fft(int)" (?forward_fft@MyFourierClass@@QEAAXH@Z) already defined in main.obj
1>CGPProject\x64\Debug\CGPProject.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

my_fourier.cpp:

```
#ifndef MY_FOURIER
#define MY_FOURIER

class MyFourierClass {
double** dataset = 0; 
//public: // <-- un-commenting this line causes the linker error.
    void forward_fft(int);
};
void MyFourierClass::forward_fft(int bins) {
    bins = bins + 1;

};
#endif
```

Main:

```
#ifndef MY_MAIN
#define MY_MAIN
#include "my_fourier.cpp"
int main() {
    int i = 0;

}
#endif
```

is there a standard method for debugging linker errors? I thought there might be a definition in another file, so I've delete all other files in my project. There is now only main.cpp and my_fourier.cpp. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Header file for the class definition. Source file for the function definition. And `#include` the *header* file, not source files.

Comment: You should split `my_fourier.cpp` into `.cpp` and `.h` and include the latter.

Comment: Thank you! I always thought splitting into .h and .cpp was optional, it works fine now. Thanks a lot! If someone answers the question I'll mark it as solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error LNK2005, already defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046485/error-lnk2005-already-defined)

Comment: @Xephex it is optional, you can `#include` anything, but more often than not, circumstances force you to go with the tried-and-true headers and implementation files approach. Any time you have functions and data definitions included by multiple files (whether the definitions are in a .h or a cpp file) you're going to compile, or a smart build system that sees the cpp file and automatically compiles and links it, you will have multiple definitions, and the linker hates that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you included the module my_fourier.cpp in the module with main using the include directive

```
#include "my_fourier.cpp"
```

then this function

```
void MyFourierClass::forward_fft(int bins) {
    bins = bins + 1;

};
```

is defined at least twice.

You should place the class definition in a header and this header include in the module
my_fourier.cpp where the member function is defined and in the module with main removing from the last module the directive

```
#include "my_fourier.cpp"
```

Comment: Alternatively, move the definition of `forward_fft` into the class definition. Then it becomes implicitly `inline`, which means it's OK to define it multiple times, as long as each definition is identical. Or, just declare it `inline` yourself. These solutions are not as usual as separating declaration from definition, as in this answer.