# UE4 Compile error with UFUNCTION(NetMulticast). error LNK2005: function already defined in *.cpp.obj

Tags: unreal-engine4

MyActor.h

```
UCLASS()
class FPS_API AMyActor: public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
...
public:
    UFUNCTION(NetMulticast, Reliable)
    void MulticastRPCMyFunction();
...
}
```

MyActor.cpp

```
void AMyActor::MulticastRPCMyFunction()
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Message"));
}
```

When i compile my project, i can check the error message below.
Compile error

```
*.gen.cpp.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl *::MulticastRPCMyFunction(void)" (?MulticastRPCMyFunction@*@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in *.cpp.obj
```

Comment: Please consider adjusting your title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error LNK2005, already defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046485/error-lnk2005-already-defined)

Comment: @ChristianB Would you recommend me how can i change my title?

Comment: @vasek No. My question is about UE4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With networked functions (in your case the `NetMulticast` metadata) you do not name the function the same thing in the Cpp file as the header file because it gets generated by UHT (hence the linker error about it already being defined).

In your case your Cpp file would need to look like this:

```
void AMyActor::MulticastRPCMyFunction_Implementation()
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Message"));
}
```

Notice the `_Implementation` addition to the function name.

If you ever add the `WithValidation` metadata, then you would need another function with `_Validate` added to the end of the function name.